# How can i make my php page send e-mail only in mondays but every monday?

Tags: php, email

I have a php file and i want it to send mail every monday to only 1 client can anybody know can it be done? or i must send mail manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a cronjob (linux) or scheduled task (windows) to execute a PHP file repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes creating a cronjob  file which runs in every 7 days time interval and setting it for monday would do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

setting up a cronjob with

```
0 0 * * 1 curl http://url/to/your/script
```

should sort it

Comment: Instead of curl you could also choose to just execute the php file by CLI